# Loss magnitude showing 0 at first epoch yet predictions are completely off

Tags: neural-networks, keras

I'm trying neural network for the first time. I'm getting a weird output - while loss magnitude is apporaching 0 at the first epoch itself, the predictions are trash! can some one explain what's going on. Here is the code I used -

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(predictors, outcome, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
cs=StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = cs.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = cs.transform(X_test)

l0 = keras.layers.Dense(units=5, input_shape=[30])
l1 = keras.layers.Dense(units=5,activation=tf.nn.relu)
l2 = keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
model=keras.Sequential([l0,l1,l2])
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))
history= model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train,epochs=500,verbose=False)

[image]

Comment: Can you properly format your post? See the guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Also, are you sure the loss is zero? Or does it just **look** like zero on the graph stretched to 60000? Try plotting from epoch 10 onward to get better scaling, or use logarithmic y-axis.

Comment: Finally, check [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-learn) for common neural network learning troubleshooting